# Issue interfacing to MOXA ioLogik1214 with python via RESTful API for PUT data to DO port

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to write a PUT data (RESTful API) to set a Digital Output channel to 1 for MOXA ioLogik1214 device.

I tried the Digital Input DI-00 configured as diCounter channel, and was able to read & write to this channel.

However when I tried to write to the DO-00, configure as normal output channel, I encountered:

"HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found" (as shown in the ## comments).

I have checked that the DO-00 is a read/write Digital Output channel. Any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

My python codes are as below:

```
def getData(url, headers):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised.
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print("HTTP error occurred: %s" % http_err)
        if (response.status_code == 400):
            if len(response.text) > 0:
                print("response.text:\n%s" % response.text)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Other error occurred: %s" % err)
    else:
        if len(response.text) > 0:
                print("response.text:\n%s" % response.text)
        else:
            print("Success!")

    # Print empty line.
    print


def putData(url, headers, data):
    try:
        response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=data)

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised.
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print("HTTP error occurred: %s" % http_err)
        if (response.status_code == 400):
            if len(response.text) > 0:
                print("response.text:\n%s" % response.text)
    except Exception as err:
        print("Other error occurred: %s" % err)
    else:
        if len(response.text) > 0:
                print("response.text:\n%s" % response.text)
        else:
            print("Success!")

    # Print empty line.
    print


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Prepare Digital Output URL.
    do00Status_URL =  "http://"+MOXA_IP+"/api/slot/0/io/do/0/doStatus"

    # Prepare GET headers.
    getHeaders = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'vdn.dac.v1'}

    # Use GET method to get DO-00 Status.
    print("1) GET DigitalOutput00_Status response...")
    getData(do00Status_URL, getHeaders)
    ## Result => HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found

    # Prepare DO-00_ON data.
    do00Status_ON = '{"slot":0,"io":{"do":{"0":{"doStatus":1}}}}'

    # Prepare DO-00_OFF data.
    do00Status_OFF = '{"slot":0,"io":{"do":{"0":{"doStatus":0}}}}'

    # Prepare PUT headers.
    putHeaders_do00Status = getHeaders.copy()
    putHeaders_do00Status['Content-Length'] = len(json.dumps(do00Status_OFF))  # do00Status_ON/OFF is the same length.

    # PUT Counter data & print result.
    print("2a) PUT DO-00_ON response...")
    putData(do00Status_URL, putHeaders_do00Status, do00Status_ON)
    ## Result => HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found

    # GET DO-00_Status Info data & print them.
    print("2b) GET DO-00_Status response...")
    getData(do00Status_URL, getHeaders)
    ## Result => HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found

    time.sleep(3);

    # PUT Counter data & print result.
    print("2c) PUT DO-00_OFF response...")
    putData(do00Status_URL, putHeaders_do00Status, do00Status_OFF)
    ## Result => HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found

    # GET DO-00_Status Info data & print them.
    print("2d) GET DO-00_Status response...")
    getData(do00Status_URL, getHeaders)
    ## Result => HTTP error occurred: 404 Client Error: Not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Just digging the same hole and found out that Moxa E1214 has digital output in form of relay. (DO != Relay).

Therefore url should be:

```
   "http://"+MOXA_IP+"/api/slot/0/io/relay/0/relayStatus".
```

and jsons for control are different:

```
    # Prepare DO-00_ON data.
    do00Status_ON = '{"slot":"0","io":{"relay":{"0":{"relayStatus":"0"}}}}'

    # Prepare DO-00_OFF data.
    do00Status_OFF = '{"slot":"0","io":{"relay":{"0":{"relayStatus":"1"}}}}'
```

Third thing is line:

```
   putHeaders_do00Status['Content-Length'] = len(json.dumps(do00Status_OFF))
```

One that works:

```
   putHeaders_do00Status['Content-Length'] = str(len(do00Status_OFF))
```

do00Status_OFF is string, no need to dump json of string and headers values need to be byte or string (requests lib requirement I think).

Hope it helps.